# Android Launcher3 search bar not visible in landscape mode. Any suggestions?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am using the [Launcher 3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/) code as a base for building my own launcher application. I've managed to build everything correctly and import the project in Android Studio, however I seem to have some issues when switching into landscape mode on a Nexus 7 (first generation) device.

The problem is that at first the Google search and voice search icons do not appear but after pressing the home button they do. Also if you tap on the places where they should be, the search activity appears and when coming back to the launcher the buttons are there too. It seem that somehow they are not visible and I have looked over in the code but so far I could not find what the issue is.

Is there any one who encountered this problem and can point me in the right direction to solving it?

Thanks,
Mihai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem.

It would seem that the `drawableStateChanged()` method from `HolographicImageView` is called when switching to landscape mode before the view is laid out. This would cause the `mStatesUpdated` flag set in the method `generatePressedFocusedStates(ImageView v)` in `HolographicViewHelper` to be set to true and the code updating the search bar ui would not be executed anymore in the subsequent calls of the `generatePressedFocusedStates(ImageView v)`, after the view is laid out.

A simple check for `isLaidOut()` before calling `generatePressedFocusedStates(ImageView v)` in the `drawableStateChanged()` method would do the trick.